# Remove left and right side of a date using python and update as new sentence

Tags: python-3.x

```
import re   
sentence = "FHYSJCAUTMERAPrJNp j lOctober 20,2017I Initial Evaluation i. Causing him  aa03-10-2020l and work on 8/7/2020mm"\
print(' '.join([re.sub('[^\d+,/]+', '', i) or i for i in string.split()]))

Following date formats are:
aa03-10-2020l  ---> 03-10-2020
8/7/2020mm   ---> 8/7/2020
October 20,2017I  ---> October 20,2017
```

The present code output is : FHYSJCAUTMERAPrJNp j lOctober 20,2017 Initial Evaluation i. Causing him  aa03102020 and work on 8/7/2020mm

Is there any solution to remove "I" from "October 20,2017I" and "aa" and "l" from aa03-10-2020l and "mm" from 8/7/2020

The required solution :FHYSJCAUTMERAPrJNp j October 20,2017 Initial Evaluation i. Causing him  03-10-2020 and work on 8/7/2020

Comment: You at least need to tell us what all the different date formats are.  And on top of this, please include your current Python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have identified what all date patterns are, you could do a regex replacement like the following:

```regex
\S*(<date_pattern1|date_pattern2|date_pattern3|...>)\S*
```

and then replace with just the first capture group.  Here is one suggestion:

```py
sentence = "FHYSJCAUTMERAPrJNp j October 20,2017I Initial Evaluation i. Causing him aa03-10-2020l and work on 8/7/2020mm"
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
months_regex = r'(?:' + '|'.join(months) + r')'
output = re.sub(r'\S*(' + months_regex + r' \d{2},\s*\d{4}|\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}|\d+/\d+/\d{4})\S*', r'\1', sentence)
print(output)
```

This prints:

> FHYSJCAUTMERAPrJNp j October 20,2017 Initial Evaluation i. Causing him 03-10-2020 and work on 8/7/2020